# Which matrices to use in Given's rotation in QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b & c \\
    d       & e & f \\
    g       & h & i 
\end{bmatrix}

If I want to zero the $d$ element, I must multiply, on the left, by

\begin{bmatrix}
    c       & -s & 0 \\
    s       & c & 0 \\
    0      & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

We end up with

\begin{bmatrix}
    ca -sd       & cb-se & cc -sf  \\
    sa + cd       & sb+ec & sc+cf \\
    g      & h & i 
\end{bmatrix}

By doing $s=d/r, c=-a/r$ where $r=\sqrt{a^2 + d^2}$, we end up zeroeing the $g$ element as desired.

in order to zero the $h$ element, I multiply by
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0& 0 \\
    0      & c & -s \\
    0      & s & c 
\end{bmatrix}

Now, in order to zero the $g$ element, what should I do? Would

\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0& 1 \\
    c      & -s & 0 \\
    s      & c & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

work?

Or does the $R_Y(\theta)$ matrix work for zeroeing $g$?

I'm asking this because according to wikipedia, [image]

What should be the $r$ when I use matrix $R_Y(\theta)$?

Comment: Your matrix is not even orthogonal and  doesn't have properties of a rotation matrix. Yes, $R_Y(\theta)$ will work. $r$ is defined analagously to the case when you eliminated $d$, but you need to take corresponding elements of the updated matrix. And you need to eliminate $d$, then $g$ and then $h$

Comment: @VorKir do you know what to do when the matrix is not $3x3$? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185146/how-to-do-givens-rotation-for-3x2-matrix-qr-decomposition?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: what you mean by my matrix doesn't having properties of rotation matrix?