# How to do Given's rotation for $3×2$ matrix? (QR decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to solve $Ax=b$ in lots of ways using QR decomposition.$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix},\ b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$I know how to do Given's rotation for $3×3$ matrices as here: [Which matrices to use in Given's rotation in QR decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183041/which-matrices-to-use-in-givens-rotation-in-qr-decomposition) But how do I do it for this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find three $2\times2$ rotation matrices $G_1,G_2$ and $G_3$ such that
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{rr}1\\ &G_1\end{array}\right]A
&=\left[\begin{array}{rr}1\\ &G_1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\ \hline-1&1\\ 1&2\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\ \hline \ast&\ast\\ 0&\ast\end{array}\right]
=B,\\
\left[\begin{array}{rr}G_2\\ &1\end{array}\right]B
&=\left[\begin{array}{rr}G_2\\ &1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\ \ast&\ast\\ \hline 0&\ast\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rr}\ast&\ast\\ 0&\ast\\ \hline 0&\ast\end{array}\right]
=C,\\
\left[\begin{array}{rr}1\\ &G_3\end{array}\right]C
&=\left[\begin{array}{rr}1\\ &G_3\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rr}\ast&\ast\\ \hline 0&\ast\\ 0&\ast\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rr}\ast&\ast\\ \hline 0&\ast\\ 0&0\end{array}\right]
=R.
\end{align}
Then
$$
A=\underbrace{
\left[\begin{array}{rr}1\\ &G_1^T\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rr}G_2^T\\ &1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rr}1\\ &G_3^T\end{array}\right]}_Q\ R=QR.
$$

Comment: You mean $G_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    c & -s \\ s & c
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yes, a matrix of that form (but certainly, in $G_2$ and $G_3$ we use different sines and cosines).

Comment: what you mean by different sines and cosines?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I mean $G_1,G_2$ and $G_3$ can have different rotation angles.

Comment: but they're all in the form $\begin{bmatrix}     c & -s \\ s & c \end{bmatrix}$ rigth?

Comment: Are you sure about all the 3 matrices? Because in the $3x3$ case, one of the matrices is different. Please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183041/which-matrices-to-use-in-givens-rotation-in-qr-decomposition on the matrix $R_y(\theta)$

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Yes, they are all in the form of $\pmatrix{\cos t&-\sin t\\ \sin t&\cos t}$ but the angle $t$ for each $G_i$ may be different that for the other two $G_j$s. As for your last comment, note that the $Q$ in QR decomposition is not unique and given any fixed $Q$, its decomposition into product of Given rotations is also not unique. In the 3D case, it is not necessary to use all types (roll, pitch and yaw) of rotations.